# Numerical computation of power differences: $x^a - y^a$

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to calculate a power difference, $x^a  - y^a$, where $a$ can be large, and the numbers $x,y$ are of similar magnitude. What's a sound numerical way to approach this?

**Note:** $x,y,a$ are all positive real numbers (not integers in general).

Comment: Note that optimizing this(if possible) would only make sense if those powers are relatively close.

Comment: Are we talking about integers?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė No. See edit.

Comment: @chubakueno I edited the question. The two powers are now the same.

Comment: Can you give an idea of how large? Past typical floating point values?

Comment: @nayrb Not so large. $a$ is large in the sense of maybe a hundred. $a$ itself fits very well in floating point, problem is that $x^a$ may not fit.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest the following. Let $y > x$. Write $d = y^a-x^a = y^a (1-(x/y)^a)$. Then take the log:
$$\log(d) = a \log(y) + \log(1-(x/y)^a).$$

You are guaranteed to be able to compute $\log(1-(x/y)^a)$ as accurately as you like since the taylor series of log around 1 has radius 1. It becomes a matter of taking the exponential of this expression. If this overflows then you have a problem in general--that is, the difference is just not going to be representable in floating point numbers.

EDIT: To give a better suggestion I'd have to see some example computations you are doing/intending to do.

Comment: In fact, if $a$ is large, the log may be more useful